# Error while using make command for kernel recompilation

Tags: kernel

I'm doing kernel recompilation and getting this error while using make command

```
/usr/src/linux-3.10.48/arch/x86/Makefile:113: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
/usr/src/linux-3.10.48/scripts/gcc-goto.sh: line 5: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `relocs'.
sh: echo: I/O error
make: *** [include/config/kernel.release] Error 1


#df -i

Filesystem        Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda9         488640 292758    195882   60% /
none              494764      2    494762    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev              492079    564    491515    1% /dev
tmpfs             494764    601    494163    1% /run
none              494764      3    494761    1% /run/lock
none              494764      7    494757    1% /run/shm
none              494764     26    494738    1% /run/user
/dev/sda2              0      0         0     - /boot/efi
/dev/sda6      142417204  98313 142318891    1% /media/lenovo/New Volume
/dev/sda5      134108900 414306 133694594    1% /media/lenovo/Windows8_OS
/dev/sda7       14504940  22200  14482740    1% /media/lenovo/LENOVO
/dev/sda3              0      0         0     - /media/lenovo/LRS_ESP

#df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda9       7.3G  7.2G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           387M  1.2M  386M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  544K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2       256M   31M  226M  13% /boot/efi
/dev/sda6       150G   15G  136G  10% /media/lenovo/New Volume
/dev/sda5       223G   95G  128G  43% /media/lenovo/Windows8_OS
/dev/sda7        25G   12G   14G  45% /media/lenovo/LENOVO
/dev/sda3       996M  497M  500M  50% /media/lenovo/LRS_ESP
```

plz check this out and answer me as early as possible.
While running make command i also got an error of some 326 MB left.

Comment: Please add the output of `df -h` and `df -i` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As make error says `No space left on device` you have ran out of disk space. Looks like you have an 8GB disk.

You need to free up some disk space or use a larger HDD.

If you are running this as a VM then you need to make sure you specify a larger disk.  Virtual box chooses 8GB by default.

Comment: No, i m using dual boot. And actually I have given 50GB HDD space for ubuntu. What should i do now? How do I go about it?

Comment: You need to check your configuration looks like you only gave 8GB to `/` see the line `/dev/sda9       7.3G  7.2G     0 100% /`